# Deserialization of a custom class object over TCP?

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, deserialization

I need to deserialize an object sent to a server via TCP, and was just wondering how to determine when I've received all of the required data to do so? I'm assuming that the data doesn't just appear all in one go; am I right? If it helps, I'm using the `[Serializable()]` attribute and `ISerializable` interface within my custom object.

Answer (score 1):

TCP provides a stream of bytes. As you suspect you will not necessarily receive it all in one go nor will you know when the stream ends for a particular message so you have to develop your own application level protocol or use an existing one to determine this.

To develop your own is simple enough, e.g. include the total number bytes as an `int` in the first four bytes so you know once you have read that how many more till you have received a message, e.g.:

```
    public static int Recieve(NetworkStream myNetworkStream, byte[] myBigBuffer)
    {
        // Read size of message being received
        var myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
        myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, sizeof(int));
        var sizeOfMessage = BitConverter.ToInt32(myReadBuffer, 0);

        // Read incoming message may be larger than the myReadBuffer size, into myBigBuffer 
        // supplied.
        //
        var numberOfBytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            var readSize = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(myReadBuffer, 0, myBigBuffer, numberOfBytesRead, readSize);
            numberOfBytesRead += readSize;
        }
        while (numberOfBytesRead < sizeOfMessage);

        return numberOfBytesRead;
    }
```

Then you would need a way to deseralize an array of bytes to/from your objects which since you have marked them `Serializable` you can use .NET's [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx)

NOTE: You need not send object's in binary form - you could send them as text (e.g. as Json or XML) which is more portable. If using binary you could share the .NET assembly with both the sender and receiver (e.g. as a .dll) so they have access to the same Types.

Alternatively use another application level protocol already developed for which a .NET library already exists and takes care of handling all the transmission/sockets/error handling e.g. [protobuf](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjABahUKEwit_LzMmuTHAhWIHaYKHYsFAXI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fprotocol-buffers%2F%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNHvsQVjSR2hNg33J9m95_S9Sv2GOQ&sig2=3hYcFYrVemjd9va1kli0EA&bvm=bv.102022582,d.dGY) or WCF for which you can use [protobuf-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/) or Microsoft's WCF libraries that come with .NET.